# MySQL REVOKE для списка привелегий

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Пытаюсь в pma выполнить

`REVOKE FILE, SHUTDOWN, SUPER ON *.* FROM 'user'@'localhost';`

pma выдаёт ошибку

`Unrecognized statement type. (near "REVOKE" at position 0)`

По отдельности для `FILE`, `SHUTDOWN` и `SUPER` получается.
В [документации](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/revoke.html) синтаксис корректен.

```
REVOKE
    priv_type [(column_list)]
      [, priv_type [(column_list)]] ...
    ON [object_type] priv_level
    FROM user [, user] ...
```

Как составить запрос правильно?

Comment: Вы ссылаетесь на документацию оригинальной MySQL, не MariaDB. В оригинальной MySQL ваш запрос выполняется без ошибок, хотя, да, phpMyAdmin подсвечивает его как ошибочный. Кроме того, в phpMyAdmin вы ведь можете управлять правами доступа при помощи графического интерфейса.

Comment: > в phpMyAdmin вы ведь можете управлять правами доступа при помощи графического интерфейса.
Можно по подробнее как? У меня во вкладке "Учётные записи пользователей" в закладке "Обзор учётных записей пользователей", можно только посмотреть, экспортировать и удалить, но не отозвать или назначить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался.
В действительности, запрос правильный и работает, только он вызывает ошибку, при попытке отозвать уже отозванную или не назначенную привилегию.

При этом, что для меня было шоком, GRANT с точности до наоборот, разрешает назначать уже назначенную привилегию, но выдаёт ошибку при попытке самому себе назначить не назначенную или отозванную привилегию, при том, что привилегия GRANT у него назначена.

При этом, конечно же, если привилегия UPDATE не отозвана, можно установить в `'Y'` столбец нужной привилегии в таблице `user` базы данных `mysql`, но почему такой геморрой?